# Querying row counts segregated by date ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab, postgresql-9.2

I've got a PostgreSQL 9.2.1 database, where I'm attempting and failing to compose a SQL query which will show me the count of distinct tests (`testname`) which failed (`current_status='FAILED'` and showing 0 if there were no failures), segregated by month (`last_update`).  Here's the table definition:

```
                                       Table "public.tests"
     Column     |            Type             |                          Modifiers                          
----------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | bigint                      | not null default nextval('tests_id_seq'::regclass)
 testname       | text                        | not null
 last_update    | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
 current_status | text                        | not null
```

What I'd like to get back from that is something like this:

```
 testname    | Jan2012  | Feb2012  | Mar2012  | Apr2012  | May2012   | Jun2012   | Jul2012   | Aug2012   | Sep2012   | Oct2012   | Nov2012   | Dec2012
-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 abq         |   2      |   5      |   2      |   0      |   7       |  4        |   8       |   0       |     6     |   15      |  1        |  0
 bar         |   0      |   0      |   2      |   0      |   9       |  8        |   8       |   2       |     6     |   15      |  1        |  1
 cho         |   15     |   1      |   2      |   3      |   4       |  8        |   7       |   3       |     6     |   1       |  5        |  6
```

At this point, the best that I could come up with is the following, which is admittedly not close:

```
SELECT testname, count(current_status) AS failure_count
FROM tests
WHERE current_status='FAILED'
AND last_update>'2012-09-01'
AND last_update<='2012-09-30'
GROUP by testname
ORDER BY testname ;
```

I think I'd need to somehow use `COALESCE` to get `0` values to show up in the results, plus some crazy JOINs to show multiple months of results, and maybe even a window function?

Comment: +1 for showing version, table definition, and expected results. Any chance you can post some sample data (maybe to SQLFiddle.com) so we don't need to make up dummy data?

Comment: BTW, check out `crosstab` from the `tablefunc` extension.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with SQLFiddle.  Are you asking to see something like 'select testname,last_update,current_status from tests' ?

Comment: Yes, or preferably `INSERT` statements. Try `pg_dump --data-only --inserts -t TABLENAME DATABASENAME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `crosstab()` function with two parameters.

Should work like this, to get values for 2012:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     $$SELECT testname, to_char(last_update, 'mon_YYYY'), count(*)::int AS ct
        FROM   tests
        WHERE  current_status = 'FAILED'
        AND    last_update >= '2012-01-01 0:0'
        AND    last_update <  '2013-01-01 0:0'  -- proper date range!
        GROUP  BY 1,2
        ORDER  BY 1,2$$

    ,$$VALUES
      ('jan_2012'::text), ('feb_2012'), ('mar_2012')
    , ('apr_2012'), ('may_2012'), ('jun_2012')
    , ('jul_2012'), ('aug_2012'), ('sep_2012')
    , ('oct_2012'), ('nov_2012'), ('dec_2012')$$)
AS ct (testname  text
   , jan_2012 int, feb_2012 int, mar_2012 int
   , apr_2012 int, may_2012 int, jun_2012 int
   , jul_2012 int, aug_2012 int, sep_2012 int
   , oct_2012 int, nov_2012 int, dec_2012 int);
```

[**Find detailed explanation under this related question.**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3002499/939860)

<strike>I didn't test.</strike> As @Craig commented, sample values would have helped.
Tested now with my own test case.

### Don't display NULL values

The main problem (that months without rows wouldn't show up at all) is averted by the `crosstab()` function with two parameters.

You cannot use `COALESCE` in the inner query, because the `NULL` values are inserted by `crosstab()` itself. You could ...

#### 1. Wrap the whole thing into a subquery:

```
SELECT testname
      ,COALESCE(jan_2012, 0) AS jan_2012
      ,COALESCE(feb_2012, 0) AS feb_2012
      ,COALESCE(mar_2012, 0) AS mar_2012
      , ...
FROM (
    -- query from above)
    ) x;
```

#### 2. `LEFT JOIN` the primary query to the full list of months.

In this case, you don't need the second parameter by definition.
For a bigger range you could use `generate_series()` to create the values.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     $$SELECT t.testname, m.mon, count(x.testname)::int AS ct
       FROM  (
          VALUES
           ('jan_2012'::text), ('feb_2012'), ('mar_2012')
          ,('apr_2012'), ('may_2012'), ('jun_2012')
          ,('jul_2012'), ('aug_2012'), ('sep_2012')
          ,('oct_2012'), ('nov_2012'), ('dec_2012')
       ) m(mon)
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT testname FROM tests) t
       LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT testname
                ,to_char(last_update, 'mon_YYYY') AS mon
          FROM   tests
          WHERE  current_status = 'FAILED'
          AND    last_update >= '2012-01-01 0:0'
          AND    last_update <  '2013-01-01 0:0'  -- proper date range!
          ) x USING (mon)
       GROUP  BY 1,2
       ORDER  BY 1,2$$
     )
AS ct (testname  text
   , jan_2012 int, feb_2012 int, mar_2012 int
   , apr_2012 int, may_2012 int, jun_2012 int
   , jul_2012 int, aug_2012 int, sep_2012 int
   , oct_2012 int, nov_2012 int, dec_2012 int);
```

### Test case with sample data

Here is a test case with some sample data that the OP failed to provide. I used this to test it and make it work.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tests (
  id             bigserial PRIMARY KEY
 ,testname       text NOT NULL
 ,last_update    timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
 ,current_status text NOT NULL
 );

INSERT INTO tests (testname, last_update, current_status)
VALUES
  ('foo', '2012-12-05 21:01', 'FAILED')
 ,('foo', '2012-12-05 21:01', 'FAILED')
 ,('foo', '2012-11-05 21:01', 'FAILED')
 ,('bar', '2012-02-05 21:01', 'FAILED')
 ,('bar', '2012-02-05 21:01', 'FAILED')
 ,('bar', '2012-03-05 21:01', 'FAILED')
 ,('bar', '2012-04-05 21:01', 'FAILED')
 ,('bar', '2012-05-05 21:01', 'FAILED');
```

Comment: Awesome thanks!  This gets me 99% of the way there.  Only thing missing is that null counts aren't reported as 0.

Comment: I thought I could force the null counts to be zeroes with coalesce, but its not having any impact: SELECT testname, to_char(last_update, 'mon_YYYY') AS last_update, coalesce(count(*),0) AS ct

Comment: Tried to force the NULLs to 0 with CASE, but that too doesn't work.  I must be missing something silly: CASE WHEN count(*) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE count(*) END as ct

Comment: @netllama: I provided added solutions for the additional problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving this a try, but the first solution doesn't seem to work: ERROR:  COALESCE types text and integer cannot be matched

Comment: The second with a JOIN also isn't working: ERROR:  column "tests.testname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @netllama: The first error was a type incompatibility. I changed the resulting type to integer to fix it. Solution 2. needed an improvement: `CROSS JOIN` the calender rows to a table of testnames to cover all rows. We did ask for sample data so we can test, and I mentioned my solution was untested for this reason.

Comment: Thanks.  The first solution no longer generates an error, but also still doesn't show zeroes in place of the null values.  The second however works perfectly!

Comment: @netllama: The first version works for me, too. (Only fixed the column alias.) I don't see how it could show any `NULL` values.